# Can't receive updates in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I just bought Asus ROG G752 which had Windows 10 preinstalled. So, I choose the standard configuration when I started it for the first time and everything was fine. However even after 3 days it hasn't installed a single update. The update history is empty and it doesn't download any updates. It is showing several updates that are available such as:

```
Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3125217)., 
Upgrade to Windows 10 Home, version 1511, 10586.
etc.
```

But the downloading is at 0% and not moving.

I tried different things, including `WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab`, but it is just stuck at "stopping bits service".

Same thing happens even if I do it with run command, it just says that it "can't be stopped".

I am out of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Windows 10 Windows Update Troubleshooter tool from microsoft, I think they made this to fix such issues:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/windows-update-troubleshooter

If this does not fix your issue, you could also try this PowerShell script to reset Windows Update, Don't forget to run as admin!

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/reset-windows-update-agent-d824badc

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the Windows key, type "cmd", right click the Command Prompt icon that appears at the top of the list, and click **Run as administrator** from the drop down menu.
2. Type **net stop wuauserv** and press the ENTER key.

> If it does not report "The Windows Update service was stopped successfully"
>
> - Try running Step 3, and then try this step once more after that.
> - If that doesn't work, try **Start** > type "Services" > find **Windows** **Update** > right-click > select **Stop**. It might help to turn off your Wi-Fi.

3. Type **net stop bits** and press the **ENTER** key.
4. Type **ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution softwaredistribution.old** and press the ENTER key.

> If you get an "Access is denied" response, then try the following:
>
> - Go to **Settings** > **Update + Security** > **Recovery** > **Advanced Startup** > **Restart now**
> - After the restart, from the blue screen of options, select **Troubleshoot** > **Advanced** > **Command Prompt**
> - Type **ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution softwaredistribution.old** and press the ENTER key.
> - (If for some reason the folder can't be found, type **diskpart** and wait till it starts up. Then type **list volume**, and determine what letter is assigned to your Windows OS partition. Type **quit** to exit diskpart. Replace the above command's "C" with whatever you find necessary)

5. Close the command prompt with the "X" in the top right-hand corner of the window, and select **Continue to Windows** from the screen of options that appears.
6. Press the **Windows** key, type "update", click the "**Check for updates**" option that appears at the top of the start menu. Once started, click "**Check for updates**" button.

Since you deleted the SoftwareDistribution folder, the search for updates may take longer than normal, but it is a small price to pay to get Windows Update working again!

Source: From my post [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-rename-softwaredistribution-folder-error/08b4290b-ef3d-4e1c-94a5-746a2066a9c2)